# Merging a list into a Dictionary with a dynamic key type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

What, if any, is the best method of merging a `List` object into a `Dictionary` with a dynamic key type?

For error reporting purposes I'm using the following `Dictionary`

```
public static Dictionary<object, string> _errors = new Dictionary<object, string>();
```

However at a certain part of the program I want to merge a `List` of objects into the `Dictionary`. The problem, though, is that I only want to include objects from the `List` that don't already exist in the `Dictionary`. Is this possible to do in a less procedural manner than looping through both objects as I've done below?

```
//'updates' is a standard List<ZipCodeTerritory> object
foreach (ZipCodeTerritory zip in updates)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<object, string> error in errorList)
    {
        if (error.Key is ZipCodeTerritory)
        {
            ZipCodeTerritory existingKey = (ZipCodeTerritory) error.Key;
            if (
                zip.Id != existingKey.Id &&
                zip.ChannelCode != existingKey.ChannelCode &&
                zip.DrmTerrDesc != existingKey.DrmTerrDesc &&
                zip.IndDistrnId != existingKey.IndDistrnId &&
                zip.StateCode != existingKey.StateCode &&
                zip.ZipCode != existingKey.ZipCode &&
                zip.EndDate.Date != existingKey.EndDate.Date &&
                zip.EffectiveDate.Date != existingKey.EffectiveDate.Date &&
                zip.ErrorCodes != existingKey.ErrorCodes &&
                zip.Status != existingKey.Status
                )
            {
                errorList.Add(zip, string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for starters, you could implement [`IEquatable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.100).aspx) on `ZipCodeTerritory` to refactor out this comparison code...

Comment: If I understand correctly I'll still have to loop through both collections even though I've overriden the `.Equals()` method. Wondering if .Net/Linq/any other library or namespace has a function that could take care of this quicker.

Comment: you are correct, it was just a comment/suggestion to help you clean up this section of code (SLOC/sep. of concerns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code sample, the dictionary's `Value` is not used, it's always `String.Empty`. Maybe a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be more suitable:

> The HashSet class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order.

Therefore:

```
var errorList = new HashSet<ZipCodeTerritory>(updates);
```

**Edit**

You would also need to make sure that the equality comparer is specified, or that `Equals(object obj)` is correctly implemented for `Equals(object obj)`

Comment: I'm only using `string.empty` in this particular instance

Comment: HashSet still feels like the best way to get non duplicated results. The set can then be queried via Linq to use however you need.

Answer (score 0):

instead of objects I would use dynamics and check in dictionary if the current list value already exists

```
Dictionary<dynamic, string> _errors = new Dictionary<dynamic, string>();

if(from c in _errors where(key.zip.Id != existingKey.Id &&
                key.zip.ChannelCode != existingKey.ChannelCode &&
                key.zip.DrmTerrDesc != existingKey.DrmTerrDesc &&
                key.zip.IndDistrnId != existingKey.IndDistrnId &&
                key.zip.StateCode != existingKey.StateCode &&
                key.zip.ZipCode != existingKey.ZipCode &&
                key.zip.EndDate.Date != existingKey.EndDate.Date &&
                key.zip.EffectiveDate.Date != existingKey.EffectiveDate.Date &&
                key.zip.ErrorCodes != existingKey.ErrorCodes &&
                key.zip.Status != existingKey.Status) select c.key).FirstOrDefault()==null)
{
 errorList.Add(zip, string.Empty);

}
```